# Remove columns of a structure based on a field value

Tags: matlab

I have a structure array called x with a field called y (there are other fields, but I want to select them based on y);

```
x(1).y = 1
x(2).y = 2
x(3).y = 3
x(4).y = 4
```

What I want is to extract the columns of the struct file based on the value of y.  For example, if y is less than or equal to , copy x(1) and x(2) in to a new struct.

I have tried;

```
for i = 1:4
    if x(i).y <= 2
       goodXColumns(i) = x(i)
    elseif x(i).y > 2
       goodXColumns(i) = []
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work.  But only using the 1st if test, it produces a structure where x(3) and x(4) have empty fields.

Comment: So you want to retrieve the `y` values to a new array, but only when the values satisfies a condition, right?

Comment: Yeh - thats exactly it.  Your solution worked, and I've accepted it as an answer...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
goodXColumns = x([x.y] <= 2)
```